# Refreshing a Morph without any user interaction

Tags: smalltalk, squeak, morphic

I am creating a board game that can have both human and bot players.

My first version, which uses the Transcript, is ready. So now I want to make a better looking, more user friendly version using Morphs. The problem is when I start the game with only bot players. Only the end board is shown, whereas I would like to see each move that has been played, each change on the board.

I have tried lots of things, with forced updates of the morph or the world. I have tried to use `step`, `stepTime` and `startStepping`.

The latter shows my I am missing something: `step` is called for the first time when the game is over. Also: I have no idea what to put in `step`. Adding and removing submorphs is done by other methods, as well as a call to `morph changed`.

So: how can I see morph changes, without any interaction like clicks?

Comment: There are many implementors of `#step`. Have you looked at them?

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia I have looked at some. But I guess the biggest problem is that step is only called after the game is practically over. Even though I call startStepping for the morph at its initialization.

Comment: Have you confirmed that by, e.g., sending something to the Transcript in the `#step` method? Also check the `#stepTime` of your board morph.

Comment: Just adding Transcript show: ‘’ anywhere in the game loop solved the problem. Now that I write this, I think that I will remove the step related methods and see what happens. Will post the results here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

step methods are not necessary, the only thing that is needed is:

```
World doOneCycle
```

anywhere in the game loop.

The “solution” with writing an empty string to the Transcript, as given in a comment, probably causes the world to do a cycle.